# S3 EMR getting folder list with delimiter

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, emr

I am trying to get the folders name from EMR. For example:

Prefix key = user/temp/

the bucket has the following objects:

```
user/temp/2000/1.txt
user/temp/2001/2.txt
user/temp/2002/3.txt
user/temp/2003/4.txt
```

So I need to get only:

```
2000,2001,2002,2003
```

I am doing the following:

```
val objectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("com.temp").withPrefix("user/temp/").withDelimiter("/")
val files: ObjectListing = s3Client.listObjects(objectRequest)
```

I am getting 0 files

without the Delimiter I am getting:

```
user/temp/2000/1.txt
user/temp/2001/2.txt
user/temp/2002/3.txt
user/temp/2003/4.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in the getCommonPrefix()